# plot data on multiple rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that is organized as follows

```
Location    Date            x1.1DCE C12DCE  Ethane  Ethylene PCE            12DCE   TCE VC
"IN-1B1"    2013-01-29  5.00    98.000  0.050   0.900   4.10e+02    5.000   12.000  5.00
"IN-1B1"    2013-06-27  0.50    385.000 10.000  10.500  2.80e+02    1.000   24.500  19.50
"IN-1B1"    2013-10-24  0.50    74.000  5.000   11.500  2.65e+02    1.000   22.500  7.45
"IN-1B2"    2007-08-28  0.25    0.280   NA  NA  1.50e+02    0.250   1.900   0.25
"IN-1B2"    2007-10-31  0.50    0.310   NA  NA  2.10e+02    0.500   4.500   0.50
"IN-1B2"    2008-04-02  4.15    4.150   NA  NA  1.30e+02    4.150   1.800   4.15
"IN-1B3"    2007-10-31  0.25    0.300   NA  NA  1.90e+02    0.250   1.700   0.25
"IN-1B3"    2009-05-06  0.25    0.170   NA  NA  2.00e+02    0.250   1.500   0.25
```

The location identifier in column 1 identifies a location where samples were collected over time. There are 20 locations each with sample results collected at various times.  I would like to create a scatterplot matrix of the results (in columns) vs time and use the location identifier to delineate the data to be included in each scatter plot.  Any help or reference would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: Do you mean [`facet_grid`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/facet_grid.html)?

Comment: What do you mean by "results" vs time? What will be on the y axis? Which of the columns?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please submit a fully reproducible (and preferably minimal) example as it makes it much easier to help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be looking for this:

```
# creating initial dataframe
df <- read.table(text = "
Location    Date            x1.1DCE C12DCE  Ethane  Ethylene PCE            12DCE   TCE VC
IN-1B1    2013-01-29  5.00    98.000  0.050   0.900   4.10e+02    5.000   12.000  5.00
IN-1B1    2013-06-27  0.50    385.000 10.000  10.500  2.80e+02    1.000   24.500  19.50
IN-1B1    2013-10-24  0.50    74.000  5.000   11.500  2.65e+02    1.000   22.500  7.45
IN-1B2    2007-08-28  0.25    0.280   NA  NA  1.50e+02    0.250   1.900   0.25
IN-1B2    2007-10-31  0.50    0.310   NA  NA  2.10e+02    0.500   4.500   0.50
IN-1B2    2008-04-02  4.15    4.150   NA  NA  1.30e+02    4.150   1.800   4.15
IN-1B3    2007-10-31  0.25    0.300   NA  NA  1.90e+02    0.250   1.700   0.25
IN-1B3    2009-05-06  0.25    0.170   NA  NA  2.00e+02    0.250   1.500   0.25", header = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)

# converting dataframe into long format
require(reshape2)
df2 <- melt(df, id=c("Location","Date"))

# creating a facetted plot
require(ggplot2)
ggplot(df2, aes(x=as.Date(Date), y=value, color=variable)) + 
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(. ~ Location)
```

The result:
[image]